# Sorting out the tilt-shift questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, mergers

These two:

- [What's the best way to create a tilt-shift photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-tilt-shift-photograph)
- [How to get a miniature effect on pictures without special equipment?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures)

are effectively duplicates. The first asks a broad question including how to fake the effect in post-processing.

*However*, the answers to the first tend towards lens-based "real" approaches, whereas the second has answers focusing on software and post-processing.

The questions could be merged, but an alternate approach would be to make the first be focused on lens-based approaches and the second on software, and delete the answers in each one that no longer match.

Anyone have a strong opinion?

Comment: I'm really trying to learn more about tilt-shift, but no one is answering my questions. They just keep getting closed. Everyone says they're duplicates, but when I look at the questions that they're 'duplicates' of, I can't find what I want. My questions keep getting closed.

Comment: @J. Walker — It's okay to ask followup questions, but you need to spell out what you're not understanding about the earlier ones, which so far really have seemed to completely cover what you've written. If there's more than that, we can't read your mind.

Answer (score 4):

If I may offer my opinion, I would - if anything - move to differentiate them. You'll have more answers, more information rather than a less information in a broader topic.